# metalness map in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made a model that consists of several pieces, mostly metal but some are non-metal. Instead of making a completely seperated texture map for the non-metal pieces I decided that I am going to make one big instead that has all the necessary textures but then I realised that I don't know if it is even possible to use metalness map with cycles renderer. If it is then how would I set up the nodes?

Regards,
Koreenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign several materials to a mesh and a material can be used by several meshes.

In this first image, 2 materials (1) are assigned to the left object (2), and the wood part has its UVs located in (3) in the texture.

[image]

In this second image, again 2 materials are assigned (1) but to the right object (2), and its UVs are located in (3).

[image]

To assign several materials, use the '+' button on the right, so that a new material slot appears.
Then assign (or create) a material for this slot.
Last step, go to edit mode, select the wanted faces and click 'assign' in the material part :

[image]

Comment: If I use two separate materials would it have any significant affect on the render time If I use the same 8192x8192 texture for both materials?

Comment: @Koreenium, this is very depending on the complexity of your materials/nodes, specially the glossy/glass parts if there are any combined with the amount of light sources. If all these is kept simple, having multiple materials will not have so much impact about render time. To tell it another way : what is hard to render is light, not materials in themselves

Comment: @Koreenium, additionally, 8192x8192 is big (in itself, not about the render time)... but surely this is ok if you need it...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do have like 10+ parts and most of them are large.